# What happens if my WhatsApp has been inactive for months?

Tags: whatsapp

If I did not turn on the wifi and mobile data of my phone for a few months (let's say 5 months), which means my WhatsApp has been inactive for 5 months, but my number is still active (I am still using standard provider calls and sms), will my WhatsApp account be automatically deleted by WhatsApp server?

If lets say after 5 months I reconnect to the internet and access my WhatsApp, will I get all the messages that were sent to me during those inactive 5 months?

If I did not get all the messages, does that mean the sender of the messages will always see 1 tick?

Answer (score 3):

**The messages are kept on the server for around 30 days, and after around half a year you're removed from your groups.**

My brother was abroad for half a year, and since he didn't had internet most of the time he deleted whatsapp from his phone at that time.
When he installed whatsapp after a bit more than half a year, he was removed from all of his groups.

Note: If you don't have internet for lets say a few days, and then you connect and want to receive all the messages from your groups - the messages and media would probably be out of order, and you won't be able to understand what was going on...
I had that problem after a week abroad without internet - when I came back all the messages in my groups were disorganized and incoherent.

---

*I know it's been a lot of time since the question was asked, but it can still be useful*

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer in WhatsApp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/24068052) your WhatsApp data will be recycled after a time period of 45 days only if the same number is used for sign in on a new device.

> To help eliminate confusion with recycled phone numbers, we monitor account inactivity. If an account is unused for 45 days and then becomes newly activated on a different mobile device, we take this as a sign that a number has been recycled. At this time, we will remove the old account data tied to the phone number - like the profile photo and status.

There is no mention of account deletion due to inactivity anywhere. So if you are using the **same device** after 5 months (and you have not used the same number on any other device) your account will remain activated.

But you will receive messages only from last 30 days according to [WhatsApp](https://www.whatsapp.com/legal/).

> If the recipient is not online, the undelivered message is held in WhatsApp’s server until it can be delivered. If the message is undelivered for thirty (30) days, the undelivered message is deleted from our servers. Once a message has been delivered, it no longer resides on our servers.